# fullPage.js with normal site above and below component

Tags: fullpage.js

I would like to add a fullpage.js component in the middle of a long page.

This is what I am trying to achive:

There would be some normal website content above and below the fp-component (fullpage-component).

When the fp-component touches the top of the viewport it would lock in place and fp-scrolling would start.

After the last fp-section has loaded the fp-component would un-stick and the user would continue scrolling the content below the fp-component.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

That's not an option that is provided by fullPage.js at the moment.

There's a [GitHub issue opened about this request](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/3205) but there's no official solution for it yet.

You can however take a look at how [others implemented it](https://www.espasso.com/storefront/test) by using `scrollBar:true`. The URL was provided in that same issue.